# Return in python, reading values from .txt file

Tags: python, printing, return

Level: beginner

Hey, i'm trying to resolve an exercise in Python.

The code is comparing userName given in function argument `print(getUserPoint("Benny"))` ,if that name exists in userScores.txt, i'd like to return user score, otherwise i'd like to return a string "-1".

If i use `print` a result is printed as expected, however if i use `return`, function always returns "-1", even if a userName exists in a file.

Looks like it reads only the first user, score values from the .txt file.

Can anybody please explain why "return" works that way in this case?

userScores.txt:

```
Ann, 100
Benny, 102
Carol, 214
Darren, 129
```

Code:

```
  try:
        def getUserPoint(userName):
            f = open("userScores.txt", "r")
            file = f.readlines()
            print(file)
            for item in file:
                print(item)
                content = item.split(',')
                if content[0] == userName:
                    f.close()
                    return content[1]
                    #print(content[1])
                else:
                    f.close()
                    return "-1"
                    #print("-1")
    except IOError:
        print("File not found")
        f = open("userScores.txt", "w")
        f.close()
        print("-1")
```

Comment: You should use `try` _inside_ the function, instead of defining the function inside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing the file after the first iteration, you should eliminate the `else` that's inside the loop and extract it outside. In fact, I propose that you should refactor the code to use `with`, it's a much cleaner way to handle closing files:

```
def getUserPoint(userName):
    try:
        with open("userScores.txt", "r") as file:
            for item in file:
                print(item)
                content = item.split(',')
                if content[0] == userName:
                    return content[1]
            return "-1"
    except IOError:
        print("File not found")
        return "-1"
```

Answer (score 1):

On the first iteration of the loop where the name in the file does not match the name you passed to the function, it will return and not continue the loop.

E.g. If you call `getUserPoint('Benny')`

On the first iteration of the loop, it will compare `"Ann" == "Benny"`

This returns `false`, so the control goes to your `else` clause and `return` from the function - no more looping.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def getUserPoint(userName):
    f=open('userScores.txt')
    file=f.readlines()
    for item in file:

        content=item.split(',')

        if content[0]==userName:
            f.close()
            return content[1]
        else:
            continue

    f.close()   
    print('UserNotfound')
    return '-1'

x=getUserPoint('Benny')
print(x)
```